# MySQL - return reference via multiple table joins

Tags: mysql

```
TABLE 'styles'
id|style_code
1|6110
2|6120
3|6250

TABLE 'colour'
id|colour_code
1|1001
2|1012
3|1033
4|1050

TABLE 'styleColour'
id|style_id|colour_id|cancelled
1 |  1     |  1      |  
2 |  1     |  2      |  y
3 |  2     |  1      |
4 |  2     |  3      |
5 |  2     |  4      |
6 |  3     |  1      |
7 |  3     |  2      |
8 |  3     |  3      |  y
9 |  3     |  4      |  y

TABLE 'orders'
id|style_code|colour_code
1 |  6110    |  1001
2 |  6110    |  1012
3 |  6130    |  1001
4 |  6130    |  1033
5 |  6130    |  1050
6 |  6250    |  1033
7 |  6250    |  1050


Output wanted (based on 'order' table):
style_code|colour_code|cancelled
  6110    |  1001     |  
  6110    |  1012     |  y
  6130    |  1001     |  
  6130    |  1033     |  
  6130    |  1050     |  
  6250    |  1033     |  y
  6250    |  1050     |  y
```

What joins are needed to reference the 'cancelled' column to the appropriate style_code and colour_code combination on the 'order' table ouput?

Please bear in mind that although it may seem odd that the 'style_code' and 'colour_code' data as shown rather than being represented by style_id and colour_id, this is required for importing reasons.

Thanks and kind regards,
Derek.

Comment: Am I right in saying that `orders.id` is the same as `styleColour.id`? In which case, the `orders` table is completely redundant (ie can be reconstructed from `styleColour` by using `style` and `colour` to look up the corresponding codes to the id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer as per comments below -

```
SELECT orders.style_code,orders.colour_code,styleColour.cancelled
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN colours ON orders.colour_code=colours.colour_code
LEFT JOIN styles ON orders.style_code=styles.style_code
LEFT JOIN styleColour ON styleColour.style_id=styles.id
                      AND styleColour.colour_id=colours.id;
```

However if you make the `JOIN`s on `colours`/`styles` being on the `id` column instead of the `code` column (I assume `id` is the primary key), it might be faster (as primary keys are indexed).

This is my attempt at that. I haven't tested it, but give it a try:

```
SELECT orders.style_code,orders.colour_code,styleColour.cancelled
FROM styleColour
RIGHT JOIN colours ON orders.colour_id=colours.id
RIGHT JOIN styles ON orders.style_id=styles.id
RIGHT JOIN orders ON  orders.style_code=styles.style_code 
                      AND orders.colour_code=colours.colour_code;
```

The reason it's all `RIGHT JOIN`s is to do all the joining based on the rows in `orders` as opposed to `styleColour`.

Comment: Hi mathematical.coffee, apologies for not being clear on my question. The tables only show a small extract of columns. The styleColours table is the full list of unique style-colour combinations which exist. The orders table is which style-colour combinations were ordered by customers (so can have same style-colour combos but for different customers).  So styleColours is not the same as orders table (hence styleColour.id is not the same as orders.id).

Comment: furthermore, styles.id is the same as styleColour.style_id, and colours.id is equal to styleColour.colour_id

Comment: much appreciated thanks, the first one seems to do the trick nicely!

Comment: If the second works too, I reckon it's faster (since I assume the `id` columns in `colours` and `styles` are primary keys/indexed whereas the `colour`/`style` ones are probably not.